# Saving multiple hibernate states on Windows

Tags: testing, hibernate, automated-testing, automated

This question is related to this one: [Automated windows restart testing](https://serverfault.com/questions/97956/automated-windows-restart-testing)

In order to automate testing in Windows, it could be useful to save multiple hibernate states and running them to see whether a new version of some software behaves appropriately in the different states. Is it possible to save multiple hibernate states?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Windows saving the current memory contents in a hibernate file.

My first thought was, sure, just boot that machine with a different OS (may be linux or even a second Windows) and copy the file to a archive. However, you probably also need to save thw pagefile than too. I am not sure what else you need. So the safest way would be to backup the whole hard drive.

That said, it might be the easiest to use a virtual machine. Than you can hibernate your Windows and backup the whole virtual machine. You can later restore it several times or restore different hibernate scenarios.

Comment: +1 Virtual machines for automating testing

Comment: +1 for VMs. VMware Workstation is superb for this type of thing.